# Python - Download GIF from a link

Tags: python, python-requests, save, selenium-chromedriver

I need some help with an issue.
I have to dayly download some GIFs from a website and develop a code in python to do it.

I can Download using request.get, but when I try to open the file it is corrupted.
Does anyone had this issue?
I have python 3.6 and selenium on chrome
here is my code since i found the image:

```
        img = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/img')
        src = img.get_attribute('src')
        print(src)
        r = requests.get(src)
        time.sleep(5)
        with open ('teste2.gif', 'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.write(r.content)
```

EDIT!!!

Sorry, find bellow my code. The problem is, this website requires login. I just added the login in the request. But still have the same problem.
I have also tryed to download with dload, but same problem
@irahorecka
@UWTD TV

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import urllib.request
from pathlib import Path
import requests
from io import open as iopen
import dload
import pyautogui
link = 'https://sintegre.ons.org.br/sites/9/38/paginas/produtos-dinamicos/meteorologia.aspx'
chromedriver = r'C:\chromedriver'
pasta_download = Path(r'C:\download')
dados_login = {
    'login_usuario': 'XXXXXX',
    'login_senha': 'XXXXXXX'
}

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
prefs = {"profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
         "download.default_directory": pasta_download ,  
         "directory_upgrade": True,
         'excludeSwitches': ['enable-logging']}

options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=options)
driver.get(link)
driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys(dados_login['login_usuario'])
driver.find_element_by_name('submit.IdentificarUsuario').click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(dados_login['login_senha'])
driver.find_element_by_name('submit.Signin').click()
time.sleep(5)
met_UL = driver.find_element_by_id('listaMeteorologia_703765c5')
met_list = met_UL.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for items2 in met_list:
    if items2.text == 'Previsão de Precipitação':
        items2.click()
time.sleep(5)
ETA = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h3')
for items3 in ETA:
    print(items3.text)
    if items3.text == 'ETA':
        brasil = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Brasil').click()
        img = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/img')
        src = img.get_attribute('src')
        print(src)
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

        r = requests.get(src, headers=headers, data = dados_login)

        time.sleep(5)
        print('status code: ', r.status_code)

        with open('teste2.gif', 'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.write(r.content)


driver.quit()
```

Comment: do you have a working code example, say with the url?

Comment: @irahorecka thanks, just edited my post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked so your response code is 200?

```
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/img')
src = img.get_attribute('src')
print(src)
r = requests.get(src)
if r.ok:
    time.sleep(5)
    with open ('teste2.gif', 'wb') as outfile:
        outfile.write(r.content)
else:
    print(r)
```

It can be a header problem in your get request.

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
```

Your new code:

```
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/img')
src = img.get_attribute('src')
print(src)
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get(src, headers=headers)
if r.ok:
    time.sleep(5)
    with open ('teste2.gif', 'wb') as outfile:
        outfile.write(r.content)
else:
    print(r)
```

I changed your code a bit:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

from pathlib import Path
import requests

link = 'https://sintegre.ons.org.br/sites/9/38/paginas/produtos-dinamicos/meteorologia.aspx'
chromedriver = r'C:\chromedriver'
pasta_download = Path(r'C:\download')
dados_login = {
    'login_usuario': 'XXXXXX',
    'login_senha': 'XXXXXXX'
}

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
prefs = {"profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
         "download.default_directory": pasta_download,
         "directory_upgrade": True,
         'excludeSwitches': ['enable-logging']}

options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=options)
driver.get(link)
driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys(dados_login['login_usuario'])
driver.find_element_by_name('submit.IdentificarUsuario').click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(dados_login['login_senha'])
driver.find_element_by_name('submit.Signin').click()
time.sleep(5)
met_UL = driver.find_element_by_id('listaMeteorologia_703765c5')
met_list = met_UL.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for items2 in met_list:
    if items2.text == 'Previsão de Precipitação':
        items2.click()
time.sleep(5)
ETA = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h3')
for items3 in ETA:
    print(items3.text)
    if items3.text == 'ETA':
        brasil = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Brasil').click()
        img = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/img')
        src = img.get_attribute('src')
        print(src)
        cookies = driver.get_cookies()
        s = requests.Session()
        for c in cookies:
            s.cookies.set(c['name'], c['value'])
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

        r = s.get(src, headers=headers)

        time.sleep(5)
        print('status code: ', r.status_code)

        with open('teste2.gif', 'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.write(r.content)


driver.quit()
```

The new lines in the code is:

```
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
s = requests.Session()
for c in cookies:
    s.cookies.set(c['name'], c['value'])
```

and changed

```
r = requests.get(src, headers=headers)
```

to the requests session i started earlier

```
r = s.get(src, headers=headers)
```

**Read my comment to**

Comment: thanks for your response. Really it was giving Response [403]. I changed as you sugestet and now I got Response [200]. the GIF file changed the size from 1KB to 8 KB. but I still can't open it.

Comment: If you use the src url you get from the code you get an working gif in browser?

And if the gif working in browser is it gif data you get in the r.content or is it text?
It is sometimes hard to help when no site is as example

Comment: Thanks , I have just edited my post with new information.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you see the gif without signin with browser? If you copy the src url from the script and try to connect to the picture without login i guess you will be redirected to login page? 

Why i ask is because yo do not send any sesion cookies from selenium to requests and in the requests module you send login data through a get request instead of post.
To login with requests the site need username, password, submit.Signin, CountLogin, CDRESolicitarCadastroUrl and POPAutenticacaoIntegradaUrl data. I would have preferred to send over session cookies from selenium to requests. I added my post

Comment: Hey @UWDT TV thank you so much. It worked now.
Just to ansewer you, when a copy the gif link in src and paste in a new tab, it go straith way to the picture the cookies stuff solved it. I just would like to understand better why the GIF came corrupted without cookies.
Thank you so much again.
Is there a way to flag your answer as a correct answer? I am new on stackoverflow.
thanks

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/13913639 you can read more how to accept an answer and vote them as helpful in link above. I'm almost 100% sure that the picture need a session cookie to confirm that you are logged in as an existing user.